# Max notation for function of two variables, when only one is free to vary

Tags: optimization, notation, maxima-minima

I am trying to understand notations such as:
$$\underset{x}{\min} \underset{y}{\max} f(x,y)$$

When we say $\underset{w}{\max} f(w)$, we mean the maximum value of $f$. When we say:
$$\underset{y}{\max} f(x, y)$$

what do we mean? Does $\underset{y}{\max}$ returns a function of $x$ only?

Comment: Yes, that is it